# I Tried to install next/head to use Head component in nextjs but I fail - npm error code 128

Tags: npm-install, next.js13

I want to use Head component in nextjs but I could not install the next/head with this error message. Anyone can help me this error. Thank you.

I tried to find solution in ChatGPT, Youtube, etc. and I could fix it.[This is the error message provided by the bash terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSEqV.png)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to `npm install next/head` because the Head component is already a built-in component provided by NextJS.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-js-next-head/